# Criterion that Borel measurable map is even

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, \ x\mapsto  |x|$. I want to show that a Borel measurable map $g\colon \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is $f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))=\{f^{-1}(A), A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\}$ measurable iff $g$ is even.

I want to solve this without using the factorization lemma.

For the conclusion, that $g$ is even, I have to start with the assumption that
$g^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))\subset f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ by the definition of measurability.

I would appreciate a hint.

Comment: start with indicator function: $g=\mathbb{1}_{A}\in\sigma(f)$ iff $A=f^{-1}(B)$ for some $B\in\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$. This means $g=\mathbb{1}_{B}\circ f$. The point is that any such $g$ is of the form $h\circ f$ form some $h$ measurable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. Prove that $A=-A$ for any $A \in f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$. To show this, write $A=f^{-1}(B)$ for some $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Then $$x \in f^{-1}(B) \iff f(x) \in B \iff |x| \in B \iff \ldots$$
2. Assume that $g$ is $f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$-measurable. In particular, $g^{-1}(\{y\}) \in f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ for any $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Now apply Step 1 to conclude that $g$ is even.
3. If $g$ is even, then we can write $g(x)=h(|x|)$ for some function $h$. Show that $h$ is Borel measurable and deduce that $g$ is $f^{-1}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$-measurable.